# Start a function from a loop but only once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops

Okay, so i am making a lobby function for an online 4 player game. Everything is set, and when all 4 players join the lobby, I want to start a countdown of 10 seconds for the players to click on accept match making on client side.(inspired from csgo)
I use ajax to call upon and refresh lobby data from a php file, so live statistics show up of who is in the lobby. 
This goes in a loop, and here occurs the problem. I want the countdown function to be called when all 4 players have joined, and to stop it immediately if a player leaves, but as the parent function goes in a loop, (using set interval in javascript), it also repeatedly calls the countdown function.
Tried this, but does not help.

```
function loadlobbymodule(x){
var spl = x.split(",");
var lid = spl[1];
    $.ajax({
    url: 'inc/fn/lobbyload.php?lid='+ lid,
    success: function(data) {
        var spl = data.split(",");
        var p1 = spl[0];
        var p2 = spl[1];
        var p3 = spl[2];
        var p4 = spl[3];
        var pl = spl[4];
        var pleft = 4 - pl;
        var p1_i = spl[5];
        var p2_i = spl[6];
        var p3_i = spl[7];
        var p4_i = spl[8];
        if(p1!=''){
            $('#slot1').html('<img src="../../img/' + p1_i +'" width="100px" height="100px"><Br><br>' + p1);
        } else{
            $('#slot1').html('');
        }
        if(p2!=''){
            $('#slot2').html('<img src="../../img/' + p2_i +'" width="100px" height="100px"><Br><br>' + p2);
        }else{
            $('#slot2').html('');
        }
        if(p3!=''){
            $('#slot3').html('<img src="../../img/' + p3_i +'" width="100px" height="100px"><Br><br>' + p3);
        }else{
            $('#slot3').html('');
        }
        if(p4!=''){
            $('#slot4').html('<img src="../../img/' + p4_i +'" width="100px" height="100px"><br><br>' + p4);
        }else{
            $('#slot4').html('');
        }
        $('#slotl').html(pleft + ' players left to join.');
        if(pl == 4){
            var accept = 1;
        } else{
            var accept = 0;
        }
        //alert(accept + ' sent');
        accepto(accept);
      }

});
}
function accepto(x){
    //alert(x + ' reached');
    if (x == 1){
        if (!timeleft){
            timeleft = 10;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            timeleft--;
            $('.h3').html('All players joined. Accept in ' + timeleft + ' seconds');
            if(timeleft <= 0)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            },1000);
        }
    } else {
        $('.h3').html('Waiting for players to join');
    }
}setInterval(function(){loadlobbymodule(loll)}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the timer global and keep checking for active players

```
window.myGlobalTimer = yourTimer()
listening_PlayerThatLeave : ()=>{
  clearTimeout(myGlobalTimer)
}

listening_AllPlayersIn : ()=>{
  window.myGlobalTimer
}

/* dont keep making a new timeOut everytime , instead use the global var*/
function accepto(x){
    //alert(x + ' reached');
    if (x == 1){
        if (!timeleft){
            timeleft = 10;
//here
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            timeleft--;
            $('.h3').html('All players joined. Accept in ' + timeleft + ' seconds');
            if(timeleft <= 0)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            },1000);
        }
    } else {
        $('.h3').html('Waiting for players to join');
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, sorry for checking so late, can you please teachl me how i integrate this into my code??